# Конфликт зависимостей

Tags: npm, install, next.js, зависимости, core

Возникла такая проблема: при команде npm install выходят такие ошибки. Как понимаю конфликты зависимостей. Как можно решить эту проблему? Пробовала удалить одну с помощью npm uninstall <>x.x.x тоже выводит ошибки [image: терминал]

Answer (score 0):

Исправила проблему. Была опечатка в зависимостях.

Comment: А как вы поняли, что была опечатка?

Comment: У меня такая же проблема

Comment: Зашла в  package.json и внимательно посмотрела, был написан случайный символ.